# How to add a node to XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a huge XML file of 9 GB where i need to add a node:

XML File like:

```
<ABC>
  <DEF>
    <GHI>
      <AB>"ab"</AB>
       <CD>"cd"</CD>
       <EF>"ef"</EF> --NEED TO ADD
    </GHI>
  </DEF>
</ABC>
<PQR>
</PQR>
```

This is fixed that need too add in only ABC tag . XDocument will need so much resources any help is appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add new node to xml tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527380/add-new-node-to-xml-tree)

Comment: @sani - No, the 9GB constraint means it is very much _not_ a duplicate of that question. The answer there is not usable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx) at how to stream in an XML document to avoid loading it in one go, then simply match on the element(s) you desire and add what you need in.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `XStreamingElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlReader/XmlWriter, XmlTextReader/XmlTextWriter (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx)). These are fast, forward only reader/writers, that do not load the whole xml in one go so should cope with large files.